# Missing parameters in module databases

Tags: python, python-2.7, pvlib

I am using `pvlib` to forecast solar installations.  I have been running into issues with the `infer_aoi_model()`.

```
def infer_aoi_model(self):
    params = set(self.system.module_parameters.keys())
    if set(['K', 'L', 'n']) <= params:
        return self.physical_aoi_loss
    elif set(['B5', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2', 'B1', 'B0']) <= params:
        return self.sapm_aoi_loss
    elif set(['b']) <= params:
        return self.ashrae_aoi_loss
    else:
        raise ValueError('could not infer AOI model from ' +
                         'system.module_parameters')
```

I see that I will need values in the selected module `series` for either B5 - B0,  'b', or K', 'L', 'n' depending on which aoi loss model is used. When I import modules from the `Sandia module` database, I see the B5-B0 inputs, however, when I take in the `CEC module` db, I do not see any of the necessary inputs as needed for AOI loss.  Unfortunately, the `Sandia Module` db does not seem to have the correct module type, and the `CEC` db always raises a `ValueError` as no needed inputs are in the `series`.

Does the `Sandia Module` db get updated? Is there another place to look for this?  Can anyone offer me help on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using default values, you can pass `aoi_model='physical'` or `aoi_model='ashrae'` when you create your `ModelChain` object. This may or may not be good enough for your application.

This github issue is related: https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/issues/289